# How to plot a summation with two variables in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, matplotlib

I would like to make a function and use pyplot to plot it nicely.
The function it self looks like this:

[image]

I am tasked with plotting C for k = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10] for x in range [-3pi, 3pi].
I also want to plot cos(x) in the same window.

Is there also a way to animate this?

my code so far is :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math 
n=0;
def C_series(n):
    return (((-1)**n)*x**(2*n)) / math.factorial(2*n)

C_func = np.vectorize(C_series)
x = np.arange(-3*math.pi, 3*math.pi, 5.0)
k = np.arange(2, 10, 2)
T = C_func(n)
plt.plot(T, k)
```

can anyone give me any pointers as to what I am doing wrong?
I did not mean for this to be a tutorial, and I got some harsh comment, but I hope that now I am trying to grab the apple.

Comment: SO does not understand tex markup. Please rewrite your expression.

Comment: You do realize this is not a tutorial-request page, right? See [ask]. Ask one specific question at a time, clearly state the problem. Here you present a task, like "Grab the apple". As long as we don't know what problem you have grabbing the apple, this question seems a lot like "I'm too lazy to grab the apple myself, please put it in my mouth.", which is clearly off-topic here. Instead, if you share what you have tried already, we can see where the problem comes from and help you out.

Comment: I have edited my question, please have a look.

Comment: Can you describe what you expect to happen, and what happens instead?

Comment: Your `C_series` should involve `sum`, no? `C_func(n)` also looks suspicious -- why are you feeding the number `0` (which is what `n` is) to `C_func()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

x and k must be the input of your function, to simplify the task we create a mesh with meshgrid and then add in one direction and we will obtain the profile of the curve for each k.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math 
from scipy import misc


def C_series(x, k):
    n = np.arange(k)
    X, N = np.meshgrid(x, n)
    val =(((-1)**N)*X**(2*N)) / misc.factorial(2*N)
    return np.sum(val, axis=0)

x0 = -3*math.pi
xf= 3*math.pi

x = np.linspace(x0, xf, 100)

plt.plot(x, np.cos(x))    
for k in [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]:
    plt.plot(x, C_series(x, k), label=str(k))

plt.show()
```

Screenshot:

[image]

for `x0 = -1` and `xf= 1`

[image]

Comment: +1, though that graph isn't very helpful. These are Taylor polynomials which approximate `cos(x)` near `x=0`. You can't even see the region of good approximation since you are mostly plotting where the approximation breaks down. On the other hand, it is OP's homework problem so they can tweak the plot range if they want.

Comment: The OP of the question is: *I am tasked with plotting C for k = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10] for x in range [-3pi, 3pi].*

Comment: Yes -- but the problem is the y-range of the plot. The range that the plot function picks isn't good. The relevant part of the graph is the part that is between y = -1 and y = 1 (so plotting from e.g. y = -2 to y = 1 might be maximally informative since it will indicate where the polynomials start diverging from `cos(x)`.

Comment: Of course, that is correct from the point of view of mathematical analysis, but as a programmer I only consider the requirement of the author, those who use the code to analyze their properties will have their criteria. :P