# Plot a Summation function on Python

Tags: python

Im trying to plot a summation function on python.
It has two variables and i found a post here ([How to plot a summation with two variables in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46573766/how-to-plot-a-summation-with-two-variables-in-python-3)) but it still didn't work.
I have two erros: x and t have different dimensions (wich is weird since i didn't define two different dimensions) and the other one is just that the graph appears but the function itself does't (i tried diffent x and y intervals and it still didn't work).

The function is:

[image: picture]

If someone could please help me.

Comment: Plot where? Please provide more details, and show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over the required `N` values (1, 10, 1000) and plot:

```
t = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
Ns = [1, 10, 1000]

# setup function
def f(t, N):
    s = 0.
    for k in range(N):
        s += np.sin(2*np.pi*(2*k-1)*t) / (2*k-1)
    return s * 4 / np.pi

# plot
for N in Ns:
    y = f(t, N)
    plt.plot(t, y, label=N)
plt.legend()
```

Output:

[image: picture]